# Selenium python unable to get console log messages

Tags: python, selenium

I cant get the console messages when i connect to a site. The only message im able to get is the console message written using `driver.execute_script("console.log('New message')")`
Anyone had similar problems with getting console messages using python selenium?

```
async def printConsoleLogs():
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
  driver.get("http://localhost:9091")

  async with driver.bidi_connection() as session:
      log = Log(driver, session)
      from selenium.webdriver.common.bidi.console import Console
      async with log.add_listener(Console.ALL) as messages:
         driver.execute_script("console.log('New message')")
      
      print(messages)


trio.run(printConsoleLogs)
```